# XCode: laying out scrolling content in IB

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, autolayout

TL;DR: What's the best way to layout over-sized scroll-view content in Interface Builder?

I am trying to figure out the least painful way to layout offscreen / scrolling content in Interface Builder.  My current approach has been to tweak scrollview content width and height constraints to see all content in IB, before reverting to proper contraints for building, but this gets to be a hassle.  That said, I would prefer to do more more graphically, and less programmatically for general ease of editing.

The general approaches that I can think of are:

1. use embedded segues to build up views in a size-accurate fashion (the most intuitive, flow-charty approach)
2. tweak constraints for editing, reset for building
3. use placeholder values / constraints in IB (haven't tried this yet)
4. layout over-sized content programmatically

In more detail, I am trying to build a vertically scrolling view comprised of sub views. Each sub view is self contained and can potentially appear in more than one context and I would like to keep them isolated (in fact, I am embedding them as well, but that does not affect the question).  What I would like to do, is use IB to layout a tall composite content view.  I would then like to create the outer scroll view with a single content view again of a container view, embedding the composite content view.  Ie. the grey content view on the left embeds the taller red / blue content on the right, and I am wondering if I can deduce the height, so it could be device agnostic (the views are square, so they will take their width from the device)

[image]

So summarized, is there anyway that I could derive the hosting scrollview's contentView height from the actual height of the content of the embedded view, or should I instead use approaches 2, 3, or other?

To be clear, Auto Layout requires that scroll view content views define constraints for the edges, and width / height dimensions.  In my case, I would like to be able to preset the width to the device width, but leave the height to be derived from the red/blue content view.  IB won't let me drag constraints between the embedding and embedded scenes in Storyboard, and when I leave the field missing, it uses the prototype values for the content height.

Is it recommended to use placeholder sizes (3) in IB to make the content visible for editing, knowing that run-time constraints will render it properly (ie over-size scroll views in Storyboard so all scrolling content is visible)?  Conversely, is it foolish to even try - should I do all scroll-view content composition programmatically (4)?

Thanks in advance.

### Edit:

Placeholder constraints allow you to get by, but force you to change the priority of the run-time constraints, and trigger IB / layout errors and warnings for conflicting constraints, despite selecting the placeholder checkbox on conflicting design-time-only constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UITableviewController` with static cells. The cells will be your content views.

You can scroll the tableview down in IB to see the cells at the bottom and you get a nice extra behaviour like scrolling the views to the correct position when the keyboard is opened so it doesn't hide the textfield you clicked on.

And you don't have to worry about the scroll view at all.

If you want to reuse your content views you can make the table dynamic of course and provide the content views by code.

Comment: That is a good answer for the question I presented.  I probably reduced it too much, as I have this problem in other cases where I just have one over-sized scene. Your point is a good one for multiple sub views as I described above though - thanks.

Comment: Even with one "oversized scene" you could use just one large cell and get the built-in scrolling behaviour from uitableviewcontroller. But maybe you find a better option that suits your needs.